# App crashes in GooglePlay store but not when developing locally on emulators and physical devices

Tags: kotlin, crash, realm

After upgrading my app to a never version and using realm database, it crashes when downloaded from GooglePlay but never when I check it on physical devices or many emulators. What is wrong? Pls help. 
In my app I used StaticObject to wrap some realm configurations for different languages and inMemory real to keep track of selected object along all the app.

problem:

```
`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: 
  at pl.nanoid.atlasotoskopii.ui.Start.MainActivity.onCreate (20)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7458)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7448)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1286)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3409)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3614)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2199)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at c.a.q$a.a (3)
  at c.a.q$a.a (Unknown Source:5)
  at pl.nanoid.atlasotoskopii.StaticObject.<clinit> (3)`
```

MainActivity:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var inMemRealm: Realm

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        try {

            this.supportActionBar?.hide()

        } finally {

        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)


        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_list,
                R.id.navigation_info,
                R.id.navigation_pictures
            )
        )

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        // Configure Realm database and create in memory Realm for selecting items

        inMemRealm = Realm.getInstance(StaticObject.inMemoryRealm)
        inMemRealm.executeTransaction {
            val inMem = InMemRealm()
            inMem.id = 1
            inMemRealm.insert(inMem)
        }
        copyDatabaseFromBundle()

    }

    // COPY DATABASE from bundle to the working directory

    private fun copyDatabaseFromBundle() {

    }

}
```

StaticObject:

```
    object StaticObject {

    // value for number of items for adapters:
    const val numberOfItemsInAdapters: Int = 24

    val inMemoryRealm: RealmConfiguration
    val enRealmConfig: RealmConfiguration
    val plRealmConfig: RealmConfiguration
    val ruRealmConfig: RealmConfiguration


    init {

        enRealmConfig = configureENRealm()
        plRealmConfig = configurePLRealm()
        ruRealmConfig = configureRURealm()
        inMemoryRealm = configureInMemoryRealm()

    }


    private fun configureENRealm () : RealmConfiguration {

        return RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .assetFile("tableen.realm")
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .modules(TableENModule())
            .name("rurealm.realm")
            .readOnly()
            .build()
    }

    private fun configurePLRealm () : RealmConfiguration {

        return RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .assetFile("tablepl.realm")
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .modules(TablePLModule())
            .name("plrealm.realm")
            .readOnly()
            .build()
    }

    private fun configureRURealm () : RealmConfiguration {

        return RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .assetFile("tableru.realm")
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .modules(TableRUModule())
            .name("enrealm.realm")
            .readOnly()
            .build()
    }

    private fun configureInMemoryRealm () : RealmConfiguration {
        return RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .inMemory()
            .name("inMemoryRealm")
            .build()
    }


    @RealmModule(classes = arrayOf(tableen::class))
    private class TableENModule

    @RealmModule(classes = arrayOf(tablepl::class))
    private class TablePLModule

    @RealmModule(classes = arrayOf(tableru::class))
    private class TableRUModule

}
```

InMemory Realm scheme:

```
    import io.realm.RealmObject

open class InMemRealm: RealmObject() {

    var id: Int? = null

}
```

Run on emulator:

```
11/12 07:49:17: Launching 'app' on Pixel C API 28.
$ adb shell am start -n "pl.nanoid.atlasotoskopii/pl.nanoid.atlasotoskopii.ui.Start.StartActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 8060 on device 'Pixel_C_API_28 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/.atlasotoskopi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
W/.atlasotoskopi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/.atlasotoskopi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
W/.atlasotoskopi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (light greylist, reflection)
W/.atlasotoskopi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (light greylist, reflection)
W/.atlasotoskopi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe14ee260, tid 8111
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe208b540: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe208b540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe41e0620)
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe14f01f0, tid 8111
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe208b540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe41e0620)
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@9195193
I/System.out: @drawable/photo1min
I/System.out: @drawable/photo2min
I/System.out: @drawable/photo3min
I/System.out: @drawable/photo4min
I/System.out: @drawable/photo5min
I/System.out: @drawable/photo6min
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe208b540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe41e0620)
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@4db914d
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe208b540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe41e0620)
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@aa9d30d
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe208b540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe41e0620)
```

Comment: Is there more information in the LogCat? This sort of problem usually indicates you've forgotten to add a library (or add the correct version) to your released application.

Comment: No, no additional LogCat information. I edited my question to include information from Run on the emulator. Why it crashes only when published on the store? It is strange to me.

Comment: did you used any google api keys?

Comment: no, I didn't use